# Getting Array out of JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, websocket, javascript-objects

I try to get messages from a Server via Websocket and this works so far.
I get back an Javascript Object and want to filter out the data I need to put it into the state of my react app.

this is the code im using at the moment:

```
connection.onmessage = function (newMessage) {

        if(newMessage.data == '{"msg":"ping"}' ){
            connection.send('{"msg": "pong"}')
        }

        newMessage = JSON.parse(newMessage.data)
        console.log(newMessage.fields)       
    }
```

and this is the object I get back:

[Javascript Object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVuM3.png)

I need the Array at args/0 
how do i get it?

Thank You

Comment: newMessage.fields.args

Comment: _the problem is that you seem to be getting a PNG file_ @JaromandaX where in code do you see that?

Comment: @JaromandaX, It seems the OP posted a image of his object.

Comment: In other words don't share relevant **source code** via images.

Comment: newMessage.fields.args gives me back an Error:

    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'args' of undefined
    at WebSocket.connection.onmessage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to rewrite `newMessage` in your `connection.onmessage` function, and may be add more logs when you get a new message. Can you try this version ?

```
connection.onmessage = function (newMessage) {
    console.log("Received new message :", newMessage.data);

    if(newMessage.data == '{"msg":"ping"}' ){
        connection.send('{"msg": "pong"}')
    }

    var parsedMessage = JSON.parse(newMessage.data);

    if (parsedMessage.msg === "changed") {
        console.log("Received changed message :", parsedMessage.fields.args); 
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can access the 'args' data in the json object like 'newMessage.args'

```js
var newMessage = {eventName: 'aname', args: ['data1','data2'] }
document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = newMessage.args
```

```html
<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: this gives me back "undefined"

Comment: try with newMessage.fields.args

Comment: yes i already did that, same problem
I tried it with and without parsing the JSON

Comment: can you copy and past the json object you get back from the request ?

Comment: When I use newMessage.data I get:

{"msg":"changed","collection":"stream-room-messages","id":"id","fields":{"eventName":"drtWNMjAmKM86hnxp","args":[{"_id":"q4NA7reJWasafwhj2","alias":"","msg":"sdsd","attachments":null,"parseUrls":true,"bot":null,"groupable":false,"ts":{"$date":1512128022500},"u":{"_id":"JTFuq3JpgchDJT3Wb","username":"admin","name":"Administrator"},"rid":"drtWNMjAmKM86hnxp","mentions":[],"channels":[],"_updatedAt":{"$date":1512128022501}}]}}

when i use newMessage.data.fields it is undefined